# TCL Proc to add trailing zero's

Tags: append, arguments, tcl, proc

proc or lappend/ string map ?

```
set max 14
set min 4
```

Add trailing zero's considering min i.e. 4th position as 1 followed by adding zero's till we reach (max-1)
Example in above case would be {1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0}

```
puts $result
{1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0}
```

Let's say my min changes since its dynamic as it is a procedural argument.

```
set min 6
```

so my output should be

```
puts $results
{1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0}
```

Basically output always is calculated from 0 to 13 and whatever is my min we start from there and add 1 in its place and then add trailing zeros to (14-1)**

Comment: If you want a 1 in the min-th position, why is there only one in the first element of the example results?

Comment: As far as I can figure, you want a list that has a single 1 followed by max-min-1 0's?

Comment: @Shawn  Normal data set would be {0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0} from 0 to 13 total 14 zero's but since we get user input either with "set min 4" or as procedural argument then my data set should be converted to or i should be getting $result as 1 followed by nine zero's  which would be {1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0} that is nothing but {"min=1 " 0 0 .... 0} and last elment of that result would be max -1 ..... since we consider starting from 0th index and not 1st.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I'm reading your examples correctly, this should work:

```
proc makelist {min max} {
    concat 1 [lrepeat [expr {$max - $min - 1}] 0]
}

puts "{[makelist 4 14]}"
puts "{[makelist 6 14]}"
```

prints out

```
{1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0}
{1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0}
```

Comment: Please read my earlier comment to your question as well